# How to pass different values including a space separated string stored in a variable to grep command

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting, grep

I have a string stored in a variable like

```
errors="ORA-01000:|ORA-03113:|ORA-01555|ORA-19815:|shutdown|ORA-27603"
```

That works fine when I pass it to the grep command like

```
more filename.txt |grep -E $errors | awk '{print $1 $2}' >> temp.txt
```

But as soon as I include a string e.g "**table found**" in this "**errors**" variable like this

```
errors="ORA-01000:|ORA-03113:|ORA-01555|ORA-19815:|shutdown|ORA-27603|table found"
```

The above mentioned grep command does not work and gives the error

```
grep: **found**: No such file or directory
```

I am sort of stuck dealing with it when space separated option is passed as an "OR" option to $error

Comment: Just enclose your variable with quotes `more filename.txt | grep -E "$errors"` (you can also use `cat` instead of `more`). Or shorter: `grep -E "$errors" filename.txt`.

Comment: The only reason your first command works, even though your variable `errors` contains the pipe symbol `|`, is because variable expansion happens after the shell determines which output is piped into which command. If you had written `more filename.txt |grep -E ORA-01000:|ORA-03113:|ORA-01555|ORA-19815:|shutdown|ORA-27603` the bash would regard all the `|` in the variable as pipes. But if you had for example a `*` in `errors`, your command wouldn't have worked since pathname expansion happens after variable expansion. The moral is that it's always safer to use quotes around your variables.

Comment: Failing to quote a parameter expansion almost always indicates an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclose your variable with double quotes

```
more filename.txt | grep -E "$errors"
```

If you had, say

```
errors="2:|a-3|table found"
```

the command

```
more filename.txt | grep -E $errors
```

would be like running

```
more filename.txt | grep -E "2:|a-3|table" found
```

since the shell replaces `$errors` with its value `2:|a-3|table found` and then again splits the line into words, which would be (for the grep command only):

1. `grep`
2. `-E`
3. `2:|a-3|table`
4. `found`

therefore executing `grep` with the option `-E`, the pattern `2:|a-3|table` and the file `found`. The content of `filename.txt` which is additionally piped into that command is ignored.